# Specifing a range as a string for countifs excel vba

Tags: string, excel, range, vba

I am trying to provide variable input for countifs, and stuck up with how to do the below.
Let me know if there is any possible way to do it.

```
 dumi = ".Range(.Cells(2, Submit_date), .Cells(lastrow, Submit_date))"
 i = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(dumi, ">=" & date1, _
 dumi, "<=" & date2)
```

Also i tried,

```
 dumi = .Range(.Cells(2, Submit_date), .Cells(lastrow, Submit_date))
      i = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(dumi, ">=" & date1, _
      .Range(.Cells(2, Submit_date), .Cells(lastrow, Submit_date)), "<=" & date2
```

But none works.. Help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like this - I have added in my own values for `Submit_date` and `lastrow` (and both dates) for a sample that looks at `A1:A10` on the activesheet.

```
Dim date1 As Date
Dim date2 As Date
Dim rng1 As Range
Submit_date = 1
lastrow = 10
date1 = #6/2/2013#
date2 = #6/10/2013#
Set rng1 = Range(Cells(2, Submit_date), Cells(lastrow, Submit_date))
MsgBox Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(rng1, ">=" & date1, rng1, "<=" & date2)
```

Comment: yeah. that works fine. thanks.
 Is it possible to have something like
   Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(formula1,formula2)
whereas formula1 has a range and a criteria.. because in my case the formula varies from one to many